# How to check which Azure Active Directory Groups I am currently in?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

It is possible to return a list that shows all the Azure AD groups the current account is belonging to?

Both using Azure portal web UI and PowerShell are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to view my group membership in the portal by:

- once logged in, click on profile in upper-right
- click the elipsis, then 'My permissions'
- select the subscription for which you want to view membership
- you should see an entry for each group you are a member, and a brief description of the degree of access

Answer (score 1):

For Portal, simply click on the user for which you want to find this detail and then click on "Groups" button.

[image]

If you want to use PowerShell, the Cmdlet you would want to use is [`Get-AzureADUserMembership`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadusermembership?view=azureadps-2.0-preview).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, somehow I can see groups that I am not a member of by going to the "Group" blade you indicated. However, I only want to see the groups that I have the membership.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few different ways other than using the Portal

**Azure AD PowerShell Module**

[Get-AzureADUserMembership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadusermembership?view=azureadps-2.0)

```
$user = "user@domain.com"

Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $user | Select DisplayName, ObjectId
```

**Microsoft Graph PowerShell Module**

[Get-MgUserMemberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/get-mgusermemberof?view=graph-powershell-beta)

```
$user = "user@domain.com"

Connect-MgGraph
(Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserId $user).AdditionalProperties | Where-Object {$_."@odata.type" -ne "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole"} | ForEach-Object {$_.displayName}
```

**Microsoft Graph API HTTP Request through PowerShell**

[List memberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
$user = "user@domain.com"

$params = @{
    Headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $access_token" }
    Uri     = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$user/memberOf"
    Method  = "GET"
}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod @params
$result.Value | Where-Object {$_."@odata.type" -ne "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole"} | Select DisplayName, Id
```

**Microsoft Graph Explorer**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com/memberOf
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- Is there a way to get my "Object ID" from Azure portal? Somehow I am not able to see it from Office 365 Portal, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/find-tenant-object-id#find-user-object-id

Comment: `az ad user get-member-groups --id user@domain.com --query "[].displayName" -o tsv`

I would like to add this method with the [azure-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli) which is more platform independent and does not require Graph Explorer permission or admin privileges to install.